# tried to access class org.springframework.beans.PropertyMatches from class org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data

I try to query a record from mongo collections use org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoOperations. I define a method like this "List find(List industries, Pageable pageable)" in CompanyTemplRepoImpl class. The run error messages show as below. When I change the method name to "findByIndustry", The error messages is gone, but I always get a list "[]" as the result. 
I have already defined a method named "findByIndustry" in "public interface CompanyRepo extends MongoRepository, CompanyTemplRepo".

1.CompanyTemplRepo Interface:

```
package com.chaoke.smart.repo;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;

import com.chaoke.smart.jpa.data.IcmsCompany;

public interface CompanyTemplRepo {

    List<IcmsCompany> find(List<String> industries, Pageable pageable);

}
```

2.impl class

```
package com.chaoke.smart.repo.impl;

import static org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Criteria.where;
import static org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query.query;

import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.Resource;

import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoOperations;

import com.chaoke.smart.jpa.data.IcmsCompany;
import com.chaoke.smart.repo.CompanyTemplRepo;

public class CompanyTemplRepoImpl implements CompanyTemplRepo {

    @Resource(name = "mongoTemplate")
    private MongoOperations operations;

    @Override
    public List<IcmsCompany> find(List<String> industries, Pageable pageable) {
        System.out.println("++++++++++++++++++++++++==========================");
        int pageNo = pageable.getPageNumber();
        int pageSize = pageable.getPageSize();
        return operations.find(query(where("industry").is("商务服务业")),
                //in(industries)).skip(pageNo * pageSize).limit(pageSize),
                IcmsCompany.class);
    }

}
```

3.CompanyService Interface:

```
public interface CompanyService {

    public List<CompanyListResult> getConcernCompanyListPageable(String account, String industry, int pn, int ps);

    public IcmsCompany getConcernCompanyDetail(String companyId, String account);

}
```

4.

```
@Repository
public interface CompanyRepo extends MongoRepository<IcmsCompany, String>, CompanyTemplRepo {

    List<IcmsCompany> findByIndustry(String industry, Pageable pageable);

    IcmsCompany findOneByCompanyId(Integer companyId);

}
```

5.service.impl

```
package com.chaoke.smart.service.impl;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.domain.PageRequest;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.chaoke.smart.jpa.data.IcmsCompany;
import com.chaoke.smart.jpa.data.IcmsFollowCompanyList;
import com.chaoke.smart.model.CompanyListResult;
import com.chaoke.smart.repo.CompanyRepo;
import com.chaoke.smart.repo.FollowCompanyListRepo;
import com.chaoke.smart.service.CompanyService;

import lombok.Data;

@Data
@Service("companyService")
public class CompanyServiceImpl implements CompanyService {

    @Autowired
    FollowCompanyListRepo followCompanyListRepo;
    @Autowired
    CompanyRepo companyRepo;

    @Override
    public List<CompanyListResult> getConcernCompanyListPageable(String account, String industry, int pn, int ps) {
        List<CompanyListResult> resultList = new ArrayList<CompanyListResult>();
        try {
            Pageable pageable = new PageRequest(pn, ps);
            // 没有industry参数时，先查询客户关注的industry，然后根据industry查询company表。
            if (industry == null || "".equals(industry)) {
                List<IcmsFollowCompanyList> list1 = followCompanyListRepo.findByAcctId(Integer.valueOf(account));
                if (list1 != null && list1.size() > 0) {
                    ArrayList<String> indusList = new ArrayList<String>();
                    for (IcmsFollowCompanyList icmsFollowCompanyList : list1) {
                        indusList.add(icmsFollowCompanyList.getIndustry());
                    }
                    List<IcmsCompany> compList = companyRepo.find(indusList, pageable);
                    for (IcmsCompany icmsCompany : compList) {
                        CompanyListResult companyListResult = new CompanyListResult();
                        companyListResult.setCompanyId(icmsCompany.getCompanyId());
                        companyListResult.setCompanyName(icmsCompany.getCompanyName());
                        resultList.add(companyListResult);
                    }
                }
                // 当传递industry参数时直接按industry查询company表。
            } else {
                List<IcmsCompany> compList = companyRepo.findByIndustry(industry, pageable);
                for (IcmsCompany icmsCompany : compList) {
                    CompanyListResult companyListResult = new CompanyListResult();
                    companyListResult.setCompanyId(icmsCompany.getCompanyId());
                    companyListResult.setCompanyName(icmsCompany.getCompanyName());
                    resultList.add(companyListResult);
                }
            }

            return resultList;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return resultList;
        }
    }

}
```

Error messages:

```
2016-04-18 11:10:18,713  WARN [AbstractApplicationContext.java:487] : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'companyService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.chaoke.smart.repo.CompanyRepo com.chaoke.smart.service.impl.CompanyServiceImpl.companyRepo; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'companyRepo': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access class org.springframework.beans.PropertyMatches from class org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1210)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
        at com.chaoke.smart.service.Executable.<clinit>(Executable.java:21)
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.chaoke.smart.repo.CompanyRepo com.chaoke.smart.service.impl.CompanyServiceImpl.companyRepo; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'companyRepo': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access class org.springframework.beans.PropertyMatches from class org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
        ... 13 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'companyRepo': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access class org.springframework.beans.PropertyMatches from class org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1120)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1044)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533)
        ... 15 more
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access class org.springframework.beans.PropertyMatches from class org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException.detectPotentialMatches(PropertyReferenceException.java:146)
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException.<init>(PropertyReferenceException.java:62)
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.<init>(PropertyPath.java:77)
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:329)
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:309)
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:272)
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:243)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.Part.<init>(Part.java:76)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.<init>(PartTree.java:235)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.buildTree(PartTree.java:373)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.<init>(PartTree.java:353)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree.<init>(PartTree.java:84)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.PartTreeMongoQuery.<init>(PartTreeMongoQuery.java:54)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MongoRepositoryFactory$MongoQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(MongoRepositoryFactory.java:159)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:416)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:206)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:251)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:237)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MongoRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(MongoRepositoryFactoryBean.java:108)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1633)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570)
        ... 25 more
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'companyService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.chaoke.smart.repo.CompanyRepo com.chaoke.smart.service.impl.CompanyServiceImpl.companyRepo; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'companyRepo': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access class org.springframework.beans.PropertyMatches from class org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1210)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
        at com.chaoke.smart.service.Executable.<clinit>(Executable.java:21)
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.chaoke.smart.repo.CompanyRepo com.chaoke.smart.service.impl.CompanyServiceImpl.companyRepo; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'companyRepo': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access class org.springframework.beans.PropertyMatches from class org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
        ... 13 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'companyRepo': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access class org.springframework.beans.PropertyMatches from class org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1120)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1044)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533)
        ... 15 more
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access class org.springframework.beans.PropertyMatches from class org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException.detectPotentialMatches(PropertyReferenceException.java:146)
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException.<init>(PropertyReferenceException.java:62)
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.<init>(PropertyPath.java:77)
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:329)
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:309)
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:272)
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:243)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.Part.<init>(Part.java:76)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.<init>(PartTree.java:235)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.buildTree(PartTree.java:373)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.<init>(PartTree.java:353)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree.<init>(PartTree.java:84)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.PartTreeMongoQuery.<init>(PartTreeMongoQuery.java:54)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MongoRepositoryFactory$MongoQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(MongoRepositoryFactory.java:159)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:416)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:206)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:251)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:237)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MongoRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(MongoRepositoryFactoryBean.java:108)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1633)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570)
        ... 25 more
```

Answer (score 2):

The PropertyMatches.forField used by org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException.detectPotentialMatches on spring data, uses two methods that were added on version 4.1.7 of spring-beans. Make sure you are using 4.1.7 or above

Answer (score 0):

Also got this problem from the wrong version of `org.springframwork.data.spring-data-mongodb`. I went from 1.8.4 to 1.9.3 to get rid of the problem.